# Adding style.scss in html

Tags: html, sass

I have been reading up on how to implement `Sass` into my websites.

The [sass-lang website](http://sass-lang.com/) gives very limited knowledge and tutorials.

I have installed sass on my `Mac` pro when I compile i get an error saying install `fbevent` dependencies.

It still compiles the `style.scss` file into a `css` file, I don't know why I'm getting that error.

Secondly, I have this set up localy at the moment on my desktop. How would I implement this on the server?

and my final question

How do I link the `scss` file into my `HMTL`?? Do I use the compiled `css` file somehow or do I link to the `scss` file .

Comment: How did you install sass on your mac? Could you provide more info about your setup? E.g. server side language you're using, local server setup...

Comment: I haven't used sass, I use less. With less I can link a .less file on my html because less is implemented in javascript. I think you can't do it with scss because that's implemented in Ruby and browsers don't interpret ruby. So yes, you have to compile the .scss file to .css first. That's how things should be done even in less. You should only use these approach while you are still in development stage.

Comment: There's no need to have Sass on your production server, you only need it on a development or build server (in this case, your desktop).  Your production server just needs a copy of the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Mac users can use [Codekit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) application for easy compiling Sass.
In other way, you must install [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and Sass gem via terminal. You can find the commands for installing Sass gem at sass project homepage header.

Sass file is compiling to css, so you shouldn't to add it into your html code. Add only output css file.

Comment: I have installed Dreamweaver cs5 with photoshop and illustrator. 

I installed Xampp for my local host server for testing environment.

Comment: I am new to all of this web development. I am 27 and only really dabbled until now. I am starting a HND in computing this September. I am trying learn and get the best tools together to create good fast web applications and websites.
    I read this artical from Smashing magazine yesterday and fell in love it.  
(http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/18/adapting-to-a-responsive-design-case-study/)

I think they done a really good job and trying to follow their good example.

Comment: I have installed Dreamweaver cs5 with Photoshop and Illustrator. 
I installed Xampp for my local host server for testing environment.
I installed Sass using the terminal as mac has ruby already installed 

    I used sudo gem install sass 

 I then created a style.scss file and used sass --watch style.scss:style.css to compile the scss file into css. 


when i compile i get a listen warning 
   Missing dependency 'rb-fsevent' version '~> 0.9' 

I have read that it's possiably due to sublime text 2 which i installed as a back up for Dreamweaver.

Comment: So I am guessing then if have to recompile every time i make changes then Sass will slow down my ability for development. 

The only problem i have with CSS is that I am no way a designer in that sense of making things look particularly pretty. 

But I do like the Idea Sass provides by creating variables that can be easily changed and the compiled code runs super fast compared to normal css.